# Pagination on Soundcloud not working with favorites

Tags: api, pagination, soundcloud

I have a problem with the Soundcloud API when querying an authenticated user's tracks. I'm currently testing on iOS using NXOAuth2 to provide OAuth2 authentication. I am not using the now-deprecated Soundcloud iOS SDK.

If I make a GET request to https://api.soundcloud.com/me/tracks.json?limit=50&linked_partitioning=1, the returned JSON contains 50 tracks, and the string "https://api.soundcloud.com/me/tracks.json?limit=50&linked_partitioning=1&offset=50" for key "next_href". Making a GET request to this URL returns the next page of tracks. This works as expected.

If I make a GET request to https://api.soundcloud.com/me/favorites.json?limit=50&linked_partitioning=1, the returned JSON contains 50 tracks, and the string "https://api.soundcloud.com/me/favorites.json?before=1395763236&linked_partitioning=1&page_number=1&page_size=50" for key "next_href". Making a GET request to this URL returns a JSON with the same set of tracks as obtained with the original URL, and the same "next_href" string.

It looks like /me/tracks.json has not been updated with the [new pagination style](https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/offset-pagination-deprecated) (still using offsets). However /me/favourites.json has, but does not work correctly for me. Can anyone else clarify similar behaviour? I am hoping there is something I have missed.

Many thanks in advance.